# Accelerated charge in relativistic frame

Tags: relativity

An accelerated charge radiates energy as electromagnetic waves. Imagine a point charge at rest in an inertial frame We are standing on a frame accelerating with respect to the charge. Now with respect to our frame, the charge is accelerating in the opposite direction. i.e actually the force is doing work on our frame to increase our kinetic energy.

*Will there be any electromagnetic radiations from the charge?  Will it be observable if there is any and **where did the charge acquire that energy?***

Comment: "*Roughly speaking, radiation from a point charge is observed, when the relative acceleration (in a well-defined sense) between charge and observer is nonvanishing.*"  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02725687

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21527/equivalence-principle-and-radiation-from-falling-particle http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21830/does-a-charged-particle-accelerating-in-a-gravitational-field-radiate . References: Cecile and Bryce DeWitt, "Falling Charges," Physics 1 (1964) 3; Gron and Naess, arxiv.org/abs/0806.0464v1 . The short answer is that this point is controversial.