# The difference between an electric charge accelerated by a constant $\vec E$ field and a charge in a constantly accelerating lift in empty space

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, acceleration

Let's consider, for example, an electron being accelerated by a constant $\vec E$ field somewhere in empty space. Now consider an electron being accelerated by placing it at the bottom of a constantly accelerating lift (also in empty space). In both cases the acceleration is constant. What's the difference between the two situations?

Is one emitting e.m. radiation (the electron in the $\vec E$ field), while the other is not (it's a locally equivalent situation to an electron at rest in a gravitational field)?

Can we say that in the case of the electric field the mass is "dragged along" by the accelerating charge, and in the case of the accelerating lift the charge is "dragged along" by the by the accelerating mass?

Or is the electron in the lift also accelerated by a constant $\vec E$ field (which is nonetheless different from the electron accelerated by an independently existing $\vec E$ field).

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21527/50583 Also, have you read the Wikipedia article on the [paradox of a charge in a gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field)?

Comment: descheleschilder How in detail the electron on the bottom of a lift gets accelerated? Think about the details on the atomic level.